# How to convert data type of numbers being added together from doubles to string?

Tags: java, addition

For my assignment, I have been asked to create a test harness which provides feedback on whether the following sums are true. For this question, I will only provide one sum as an example. I have been asked to produce the following:

- TestCalculator has a method called testParser() which:
- Tests that x("12 + 5") returns a Double with the value 17
  I have been given a template in which to set this out on which looks like this:

**Template**

```
public class TestCalculator {
        Double x;
        /*
        * Adds the parameter x to the instance variable x and returns the answer as a Double.
        */
        public Double x(Double x){
                System.out.println("== Adding ==");
                //Sum here
                return new Double(0);
        }
        public void testParsing() {

         if (//condition) == 17) {
            System.out.println("Adding Success");}
            else {
                    System.out.println("Adding Fail");
                    }

        }
```

And this is what I've managed to come up with so far:

**Current program...Main class**

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

TestCalculator call = new TestCalculator();

call.testParsing();

}
}
```

**TestCalculator class**

```
public class TestCalculator {
        Double x;
        Double doubleObject = 1.0;
        /*
        * Adds the parameter x to the instance variable x and returns the answer as a Double.
        */
        public Double x(Double x){
                System.out.println("== Adding ==");
                this.x = 12.0;
                x = 5.0;
                return new Double(0);
        }
        public void testParsing() {

         if (x(doubleObject) == 17) {
            System.out.println("Adding Success");}
            else {
                    System.out.println("Adding Fail");
                    }

        }
}
```

I have two main queries. **Firstly**, I have been asked to test if "x("12 + 5") returns a Double with the value 17". I can see that this has been laid out so that the sum is a data type of String and I am confused as to why or how you would perform this calculation using the string data type.

**Secondly**, Within my current version of the program, the output returns that the adding calculation failed because I cannot access the returned double value of the calculation. But I am unsure of how I would access that value in my if statement and also return the output of the calculation and put it into the Double value that is returned in the method.

I have tried to make the question as clear and concise as possible for the reader to understand, any help on this would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: learn what the difference between `this.x` and `x` is.  Also `return new Double(0);` - guess what - returns 0

Comment: You also say `adding` but I can see no adding taking place.

Comment: Also very very confusing to have `x` and a method, `x` as a field and `x` as a parameter.

Comment: How would I make it so the calculation returns a new Double value?

Comment: I agree on that, the assignment is abut scope so I think that's why it's that way.

Comment: *I can see that this has been laid out so that the sum is a data type of String* - where can you see this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to return a new value that `adds` two values consider

```
public Double x(Double x){
            System.out.println("== Adding ==");
            //Sum here
            this.x = x;
            return new Double(x + 5);
}
```

Called as

```
if (x(12.0) == 17.0) {
```